# PowerShell Sort file 2 by column in file 1

Tags: powershell

I have 2 txt files.

```
File 1                        File2
sql00003 test1.txt            test1.txt 
sql00002 test3.txt            test3.txt 
sql00001 test5.txt            test5.txt
```

File 1 needs to be sorted by column 1 then file2 needs to be in the same sequence as file 1

```
(sorted by col2 of file1)
test5.txt
test3.txt
test1.txt
```

Is that possible to do with Powershell?

Comment: It is possible, but you'll need to provide a better example of the data you're working with, as well as the code you've tried so far.

Comment: The files are defined just as you seen them file 1 has seq number in col 1-8 file name in col 10-18 File 2 has file name in col 1 I had it in 2 steps first sort the file using col 1 thru 8 gc 'C:\Users\Bruce\process.txt' | sort | get-unique > 'C:\Users\Bruce\sorted.process.txt' then have a 2nd step to put file 2  in correct sequence Import-csv C:\Users\Bruce\sorted.process.txt |sort-object Col2 | out-file C:\Users\Bruce\Serena\ -recurse

Answer (score 0):

The problem statement is somewhat odd, just like some piece of key info is missing either on file contents or the sorting rules.

As far as I understand the question, why bother sorting the second file at all? As per your data, it contains a subset of first file's content. Just extract the first file's second column after sort like so,

```
# Declare headers so file looks like CSV
$f = Import-Csv file1.txt -Delimiter " " -Header sql, file
# CSV is structured, so it can be sorted by column
$sorted = $f | sort -Property sql
# Extract only the file column and add its content to new file  
$sorted | select -ExpandProperty file | set-content file1b.txt

# Output    
cat file1b.txt
test5.txt
test3.txt
test1.txt
```

If this is not what you are after, please add more content to the question.